# Are ["abcd"] and [["abcd"]] the same?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, rest-assured

I have used a Java ArrayList. Shen I inserted one element in the list and I have converted the Validatable response to an array list when I used assert equals it is showing that both are different
like one is [abcd] other is [[abcd]].

```
Validatable response = given().spec(request).filter(new ErrorLoggingFilter(errorPrintStream)).pathParams("","").when.post(endpoint).then()
```

The response is of the form ArrayList when I printed that it came of the form [[abcd]].

Comment: One is an array containing `abcd` and the other is an array containing an array containing `abcd`.

Comment: How to access the second one?

Comment: `[[abcd]]` is basically an array inside an array. First you need to access the outer array, which you access like any other array. The result of that is another array, which you then *again* access like any other array.

Comment: Neither is valid java code, so your question does not make any sense, IMHO. Please provide some code snippet to explain your question.

Comment: Are you talking about arrays or ArrayList’s? I believe this question could be improved with some code.

Comment: yes I am using rest assured and these are extracted from response

Comment: One's a box containing something. The other's a box containing a box containing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, ["abcd"] and [["abcd"]] are completely different. Let us understand why.
Let us consider an array ["abcd"]. As you can see, it contains only one element i.e. "abcd". So this is an array that contains a single string value. Now for [["abcd"]], the outer array contains another array inside of it and the inner array contains "abcd". Though their ultimate content seem to be same, they are absolutely different. One is a string array (an array that contains a string value) and the other is an array of string arrays.

Comment: This is a duplicate of the already posted answers, just with more words.

Answer (score 2):

*To my knowledge, these two are different things*
["abcd"] this means an array has one string "abcd" element.
[["abcd"]] this means an array has one array ["abcd"] element.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely different, a one-dimensional array, a two-dimensional array,in many languages,reference form it, [0] and [0][0]